# How to generate smooth graph using stat_summary_2d?

Tags: r, ggplot2, smoothing

The code to generate sample dataset:

```
templ = data.frame(count = c(200,225,610,233,250,210,290,255,279,250),
                  temperature = c(12.2,11.6,12,8.5,4,8.2,9.2,10.6,10.8,10.9),
                  relative_humidity_percent = c(74,78,72,65,77,84,83,74,73,75))
```

I used stats_summary_2d to generate the following graph:

```
ggplot(templ, aes(temperature, relative_humidity_percent, z = count)) +
  stat_summary_2d(bins = 5) +
  viridis::scale_fill_viridis() +
  theme_classic()+
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "black"))
```

[image]

But I want the graph to be more smooth, something like:

[image]

Is it possible to generate this type of graph by using `stats_summary_2d`?

I googled and found very few result about this...

Comment: The error message:```Did you forget to specify a `group` aesthetic or to convert a numerical variable into a factor? ``` appeared. I had tried before and because of the above reason, so I tried stats_summary_2d instead of geom_density_2d_filled...

Answer (score 2):

You could `tidyr::uncount()` your data, then use `geom_density_2d_filled()`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

templ %>%
  uncount(count) %>%
  ggplot(aes(temperature, relative_humidity_percent)) +
  geom_density_2d_filled(show.legend = FALSE) +
  theme_classic() +
  coord_cartesian(expand = FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: I already tried and the following error is given:```Error in `geom_density_2d_filled()`: ! Problem while computing stat. ℹ Error occurred in the 1st layer. Caused by error in `seq_len()`: ! argument must be coercible to non-negative integer Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred. Warning messages: 1: Computation failed in `stat_density2d_filled()` Caused by error: ! cannot allocate vector of size 2.7 Gb```

Comment: ```2: In min(x, na.rm = na.rm) :   no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf 3: In max(x, na.rm = na.rm) :   no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf 4: In max(f) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf```

Comment: The actual dataset has 3641 rows and 3 columns(i.e. temp, relative_humidity, count), every values in `count` variable are greater than 100. Therefore, using tidyr::uncount will produce a 2.7gb vector, which is greater than the remaining ram of my computer...

Comment: This definitely isn’t an optimal solution, but if you’re willing to sacrifice some precision, you could try transforming count to `round(count / 10)` before `uncount()`ing?